# BEGINNER: REGEX Match numeric sequence except where the word "CODE" exists on a line

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I've been able to stumble my way through regular expressions for quite some time, but alas, I cannot help a friend in need.

My "friend" is trying to match all lines in a text file that match the following criteria:

1. Only a 7 to 10 digit number (0123456 or 0123456789)
2. Only a 7 to 10 digit number, then a dash, then another two digits (0123456-01 or 0123456789-01)
3. Match any of the above **except** where the words Code/code or Passcode/passcode is **before** the numbers to match (Such as "Access code: 16434629" or "Passcode 5253443-12")
4. **EDIT**: Only need the numbers that match, nothing else.

Here is the nastiest regex I have ever seen that "he" gave me:

```
^(?=.*?[^=/%:]\b\d{7,10}((\d?\d?)|(-\d\d))?\b)((?!Passcode|passcode|Code|code).)*$
```

...

**Question**: Is there a way to use a short regex to find all lines that meet the above criteria?

Assume PCRE. My friend thanks you in advance.  ;-)

BTW - I have not been able to find any other questions listed in stackoverflow.com or superuser.com which can answer this question accurately.

**EDIT**: I'm using Kodos Python Regex Debugger to validate and test the regex.

Comment: What do you mean by "Exactly a 7 to 10 digit number"? Do you mean "Exactly a 7 *or* 10 digit number"?

Comment: I feel like I'm saying this a lot lately, but why not do it in two steps: (1) skip any line starting with 'Access' or 'Passcode' and then (2) check the other lines for the numerical requirement. Also, I don't understand your requirements: is the connection between your (1) and (2) `and` or `or`? (Based on the regex, it's `or`, but I'm not sure.)

Comment: What if there is a line with more than one number and the word code is only before one of the two numbers, eg. '0123456 Access code: 1234567'? Should this line match or not?

Comment: What tool or programming language are you using?

Comment: @Mark Byers:
1. "Exactly a" is overkill. Simply stated, I just need to match 7 to 10 digit number.
2. PCRE should cover the second question. The tool I'm using is DLP, which uses regex to find sensitive data.

Comment: @Telemachus: If you have a way to break it into two parts, I'm all eyeballs. The only problem is that some applications won't accept the two-part method... just a lightweight single line that is supposed to fix all of the world's problems.

Comment: @Mark Byers again: If there is a line with more than one number code, as in your example, then yes, it should match.

Comment: By the way, I'm using Kodos Python Regex Debugger to validate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
(?<!(?:[Pp]asscode|[Cc]ode).*)[0-9]{7,10}(?:-[0-9]{2})?
```

Commented version:

```
(?<!                 # Begin zero-width negative lookbehind. (Makes sure the following pattern can't match before this position)
(?:                  # Begin non-matching group
[Pp]asscode          # Either Passcode or passcode
|                    # OR
[Cc]ode              # Either Code or code
)                    # End non-matching group
.*                   # Any characters
)                    # End lookbehind
[0-9]{7,10}          # 7 to 10 digits
(?:                  # Begin non-matching group
-[0-9]{2}            # dash followed by 2 digits
)                    # End non-matching group
?                    # Make last group optional
```

Edit: final version after comment discussion -

```
/^(?!\D*(?:[Pp]asscode|[Cc]ode))\D*([0-9]{7,10}(?:-[0-9]{2})?)/
```

(result in first capture buffer)

Comment: Nicely done! Only thing I would add is `:?` after `(?:[Pp]asscode|[Cc]ode)`.

Comment: Nice on the commented version. The `//x` modifier is *always* your friend (though I would condense it down a little - the "begin/end non-matching group"s seem a little excessive).

Comment: @Dav: When I use your regex in perl as:
if(m{(?<!(?:[Pp]asscode|[Cc]ode).*)[0-9]{7,10}(?:-[0-9]{2})?})
I get:
Variable length lookbehind not implemented in regex;
Am I missing somthing?

Comment: The "excessive commenting" is mostly just due to posting on SO. Not the kind of commenting I'd use in my own code. :) But I figure for SO, more information is better than less, since there's no assumption on what any particular reader might know.

Comment: Oh, bzabhi - you might need to modify the `.*` in the lookbehind; your definition of "comes before" for the passphrase bit was a bit vague.

Comment: Dude, your commenting is perfect for us wobbly regex wannabe's! I love the delimiting breakdown of what each part does! Sadly though, this solution isn't working for me. :-(

Comment: Oh right, lookbehind with variable quantifiers is tricky. You want to re-write it with a lookahead instead: `/(?!\D*(?:[Pp]asscode|[Cc]ode))\D*[0-9]{7,10}(?:-[0-9]{2})?/`

Comment: Erm, anchor that pattern at the start.

Comment: The look ahead assertion works better, however, now it will match the numbers and everything BEFORE it also. I just need to match the numbers. How can you place boundaries for the numbers?

Comment: Look ahead with word boundaries:   (?!\D*(?:[Pp]asscode|[Cc]ode))\b\D?[0-9]{7,10}(?:-[0-9]{2})?\b

Comment: The question says you just need to match all lines that meet the requirements. If you need to extract the number itself with the same regex, use a capturing group around the parts you want: `/^(?!\D*(?:[Pp]asscode|[Cc]ode))\D*([0-9]{7,10}(?:-[0-9]{2})?)/` Then the numbers themselves will be in the first capture buffer.

Comment: just put a capture group around the numbers by adding parentheses around the part you want to match, and then look at the captured group text instead of the entire match text.

Comment: Although, if the tool you're looking at doesn't allow you to look at capture buffers, you might have an issue there. How well-defined is the location of your passphrase text?

Comment: @Murdoch Ripper: Can you tell us which solution works? The best i could find on this thread fails for 'level1: 01234567' (it doesn't match, but it should).

Comment: The regex I posted will fail if there are any digits not part of the number preceding it. You could probably adjust it a little to use word boundaries and `.` instead of `\D`, which would solve this.

Comment: @Anon: I still don't think that it would work in all cases. I think using a variable width lookahead is not a suitable approach. You risk looking ahead too far and giving a false negative in the special case I mentioned in the comments. I've already provided a solution that works below.

Answer (score 1):

You can get by with a nasty regex you have to get help with ...

... or you can use two *simple* regexes. One that matches what you want, and one that filters what you *don't* want. Simpler and more readable.

Which one would you like to read?

```
$foo =~ /(?<!(?:[Pp]asscode|[Cc]ode).*)[0-9]{7,10}(?:-[0-9]{2})?/
```

or

```
$foo =~ /\d{7,10}(-\d{2})?/ and $foo !~ /(access |pass)code/i;
```

Edit: case-insensitivity.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I'm stuck with the nasty solution I suppose. Although you're right - having two is better in this case - it won't appease those higher beings called "share holders". This is due to having a software solution which does not accept the "filter" regex. Do you have an example? I could give it a shot, but in testing much simpler cases thus far, it hasn't worked well if at all.

Comment: Your example is what I was asking for. The term "it" = using two simple regexes.

Comment: The first version isn't PCRE and the second version doesn't do what he wants.